# Use the Web Share Target API on PWAs in IOS

Tags: javascript, android, ios, progressive-web-apps

is it possible to use the Web Share Target API to upload a photo from the mobile gallery into the PWA in IOS? I read in some articles that it is only possible for Android devices but I could not find any replacement for this feature in IOS.

Comment: Right now I don't think Safari supports the Web Share Target API. So no
But you should be able to just use a traditional file upload from within the application to access the gallery. Maybe not what you really want, but I know that and camera access work on iOS.

Answer (score 5):

It is currently not possible to use the share target API on iOS. Would love to see it too.

Comment: See https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_manifest_share_target